# Using Node JS client I tried to send email via Sendgrid web API but CC or BCC not working

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid v6.4.0, sending email using dynamic template to cc & bcc is ignored. Find the payload below -

```
{
  subject: 'Hello world',
  message: 'Hello plain world!',
  from: 'abcd@abcd.com',
  to: 'a@b.com',
  cc: 'b@b.com'
  bcc: 'c@b.com'
};
```

CC and BCC is ignored and only email received by `a@b.com`

Note: I found a similar question question but it was unanswered. [sendgrid : add cc in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099882/sendgrid-add-cc-in-email)

Answer (score 2):

For sending a single email to a single recipient with a cc and bcc

```
    const msg = {
      "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "a@b.com"
        }
      ],
      "cc": [
        {
          "email": "b@b.com"
        }
      ],
"bcc": [
            {
              "email": "c@b.com"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
          from: 'abcd@abcd.com',
          subject: 'Hello World',
          text: 'Hello plain world',
        };
        
        sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
          console.log('emails sent successfully!');
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

For more info refer [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/#sending-a-single-email-to-a-single-recipient-with-a-cc-and-a-bcc)